# How do I use factorial (!) in a vega formula transform

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am trying to create a histogram of a [binomial distribution PMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) using a vega js specification.

How is this usually done? The [vega expressions](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/) does not include functions for *choose*, or *factorial*, nor does it include a binomial distribution under the [statistical functions](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#statistical-functions).

I also cannot seem to reference other functions within the vega specification (i.e. for yval below).

```
  "data":[
{"name": "dataset",
"transform": [
  {"type":"sequence", "start": 1, "stop": 50, "step": 1, "as": "seq" },
  {"type": "formula", "as": "xval", "expr": "if(datum.seq<nval,datum.seq,NaN)"},
  {"type": "formula", "as": "yval", "expr": "math.factorial(datum.xval)
  " }
]}],
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no factorial operation available, but one suitable option might be to approximate it with [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), or perhaps a [Stirling series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates) if more accuracy is required.

For example, in Vega-Lite ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"n": 0, "factorial": 1},
      {"n": 1, "factorial": 1},
      {"n": 2, "factorial": 2},
      {"n": 3, "factorial": 6},
      {"n": 4, "factorial": 24},
      {"n": 5, "factorial": 120},
      {"n": 6, "factorial": 720},
      {"n": 7, "factorial": 5040},
      {"n": 8, "factorial": 40320},
      {"n": 9, "factorial": 362880},
      {"n": 10, "factorial": 3628800}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "datum.n == 0 ? 1 : sqrt(2 * PI * datum.n) * pow(datum.n / E, datum.n)",
      "as": "stirling"
    },
    {"fold": ["factorial", "stirling"]}
  ],
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "n", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"type": "log"}},
    "color": {"field": "key", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]